# Alter all tables data types from text to varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I've migrated a postgresql database to SQL Server 2016, where all my text columns had the `TEXT` data type. I realised that `TEXT` should not be used in SQL Server.

Is there a simple query to change all text columns data types from `TEXT` to `VARCHAR(MAX)` in SQL Server?

I've found this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/66394) but is limited by column name. I want to do it all at once.

```
 select 
     'alter table '||table_schema||'.'||table_name||' alter column'||column_name||' type text;'
 from 
     information_schema.columns
 where 
     table_schema = 'public'
     and column_name = 'description'
     and data_type = 'text';
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to generate the commands, you could use something like this:

```
select 
  'use ' + quotename(c.table_catalog) + '; alter table ' 
  + quotename(c.table_schema) + '.' + quotename(c.table_name) 
  + ' alter column ' + quotename(c.column_name) + ' varchar(max);'
from information_schema.columns as c
  inner join information_schema.tables t 
    on c.table_name = t.table_name 
   and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
where c.data_type = 'text' 
  and t.table_type = 'base table'
```

---

If you want to generate and execute it automatically:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = stuff((
    select 
      char(10)+'use ' + quotename(c.table_catalog) + '; alter table ' 
      + quotename(c.table_schema) + '.' + quotename(c.table_name) 
      + ' alter column ' + quotename(c.column_name) + ' varchar(max);'
    from information_schema.columns as c
      inner join information_schema.tables t 
        on c.table_name = t.table_name 
      and c.table_schema = t.table_schema
    where c.data_type = 'text' 
      and t.table_type = 'base table'
    for xml path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,1,'')

select CodeGenerated = @sql; /* preview code generated */
--exec sp_executesql @sql; /* uncomment to execute after previewing */
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/AIYG12069

Comment: great. Just got the queries, I'll execute them. Thanks!